# having the border not expanded the width of an element

Tags: css

I though I remembers there being a css properly that I could set that would allow me to set a border but it would not expand the size of the element.  for example, if I set the width to 100 and a border of one 1 all around, the element width becomes 102.

Is their a property to keep the element at 100?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're thinking of `box-sizing: border-box`.

The spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing

```css
#whatever {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Practical usage information: http://html5please.com/#box-sizing

Browser support: http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing

Comment: That is not what I was thinking but it does what I am looking for the best

Comment: If that wasn't it, the only other thing I can imagine you were thinking of is [IE's buggy old box model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug), which just so happens to match `box-sizing: border-box`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `outline`, which does not take up any space:

```
outline: 1px solid black;
```