# Adding border on hover expands element

Tags: css

I have this setup:

```
<div class="outer" id="elem1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>

.outer {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    
    box-sizing: border-box; 
}
#elem1{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    background:#ccc;
    color:white;
    padding:5px;
 }
.chover{
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

As you can see on hover element size expands and I am trying to prevent that:

http://jsfiddle.net/nVaE9/38/

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940632/having-the-border-not-expanded-the-width-of-an-element

Comment: Of course it expands. You gave it border on hover. It expands 1 px.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a transparent border to `.outer`

```
.outer {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

which will then be replaced with a red border of the same width.

---

It can be achieved without jQuery though:

```
.outer {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
#elem1 {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    background:#ccc;
    color:white;
    padding:5px;

}
.outer:hover {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```
border: 1px solid #ccc;
```

to #elem1

and change

```
border: 1px solid red;
```

for that

```
border: 1px solid red !important;
```

in .chover

Answer (score 0):

Box-Sizing doesn't work in this way, if you don't specify a size,

Give the element a width and a height, even if it is % based and it will work as you expect

Comment: +1 this is the only answer that state the issue the OP is facing. You could elaborate though on why the box expands if OP doesn't specify a size to the box

Comment: In my opinion giving an element a specific height and width simply to achieve an affect should be avoided.

Comment: @AndyG you are right, the solution you provide in your answer should suit OP better but it doesn't explain why the box-sizing property isn't working.

Comment: @web-tiki Despite the title the issue is not related to box-sizing, because no widths or heights are specified. I'm in two minds though as to whether this contributes to the answer. It is probably more appropriate to modify the title?

Comment: I have modified the title to reflect the issue.